# In XML, is there a way to turn all of a node's children into a single string including the nested XML tags?

Tags: html, xml, parsing, children

I have bits like the following in an XML file that is a data source for an HTML page that uses CSS and javascript only. The special XML codes are my own, and I want to process them with javascript.

```
<listitem>regular text could be in here</listitem>
<listitem>possibly with <b>HTML markup</b></listitem>
<listitem>or <special>special xml</special></listitem>
```

What I dream of is a way to get from .getElementsByTagName("listitem") to the following array.

```
["regular text could be in here", "possibly with <b>HTML markup</b>", "or <special>special xml</special>"]
```

That way, I could process each listitem as part of the array. However, the XML parser breaks apart all the XML for each listitem. Other than using CDATA, which gets messy, is there another way?

Comment: You could escape the contained `<` characters as `&lt;`, but that too "gets messy." The right answer is to handle the XML structure as XML structure, and write your Javascript to process it as such... or, if you must, write a Javascript function that serializes the subtree into a string so you can waste time picking it apart again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("listitem")).map(function(x) {return x.innerHTML})
```

It will return:

```
["regular text could be in here", "possibly with <b>HTML markup</b>", "or <special>special xml</special>"]
```

Comment: Thank you; this works great in Mozilla, but not in WebKit (at least Safari). See this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170911/does-innerhtml-work-with-xml-elements . So the solution is to make an XMLserializer (such as var mySerializer = new XMLSerializer();) and replace the function at the end of your line of code with {return mySerializer.serializeToString(x)}. Works everywhere I tried so far. Regardless, in general, if the HTML is actually XHTML (as mine is), this approach seems like a no-brainer. (Or is there a caveat to it?)