# Alternatives for jQuery .html() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am currently developing a single page application, using phonegap. What i am trying to realize is to initially parse a xml file and store the content for further usage.

At the moment everything works fine but there is one major problem:

Within my xml file there is a a tag  which contains html formatted text content. For example:

```
<textfield> <h1>Title</h1> Content </textfield>
```

What i currently do is to load my xml file via jQuery ajax call and then use the html() method to retrieve my textfield html:

```
this.description = $(Obj).find("textfield").html();
```

On Google Chrome, Firefox and Android this works fine. The html is stored an can later be appended to my objects. However on Safari and therefore on Iphone devices the html() does not work. Now i am looking for a workaround. I certainly do not want to use text() because my formatting will be ignored.

EDIT: My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: Controller.baseURL+"/"+name+".xml",
    async: false,
    timeout:3000,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("succ");
        xml = data;
    },
     error: function () {
        alert('error!');
    }
});
```

Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of search I finally found my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789924/3566334

It seems that

> In IE 9, 10 and 11, Safari 7.0 and Opera 12, the nodes in doc have neither an innerHTML field nor an xml field

I followed the advice of using [XML Serializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var parsed = parser.parseFromString(yourXMLStringLoadedViaAjax, 'text/xml');
var textfieldConetent = parsed.querySelector('textfield').innerHTML;
```

Comment: It seems it does not work for me. If you look at my ajax call, my xml object is already a dom element. Now if i am doing     alert(xml.querySelector('textfield').innerHTML); it contains the content on Chrome and Firefox but is undefined on Safari.

Comment: Hey, @Dede1989. Could you please check `parsed.querySelector('textfield').innerHTML;` with some other node, not `textfield`?