# Attaching <head> elements with Javascript works with .innerHTML, but not XML child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, dom

There are probably easier ways to do this, but I'm trying something new.

The basic gist is that I want to have one JS and one jQuery attachment per head per page on my static website. I want to be able to append elements to the body, but head as well. My files are:

home.html

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="eco.js"></script>
</head>
```

eco.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onload = postdata;
    ajax.open("GET", ADDRESS, true);
    ajax.send();
} );

function postdata() {
    var xml = jQuery.parseXML(this.responseText);
    $("head").append(xml.querySelector("head").childNodes);
}
```

and common.xml

```
<head>
    <link href='eco.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /> 
    <link href='home.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /> 
</head>
```

However, this does not work (common.xml is requested and retrieved successfully). Chrome dev tools show that the xml nodes are appended successfully as well, into the head. Yet the page does not reflect the changes, notably the css is not incorporated. However, if I change

```
    var xml = jQuery.parseXML(this.responseText);
    $("head").append(xml.querySelector("head").childNodes);
```

to

```
$("head").append(this.responseText);
```

(and fix the common.xml to remove the unneeded tags) then the page reflects changes. Could anyone explain what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery.parseXML()` returns an `XMLDocument` object which represents a generic XML DOM, which is not compatible with the HTML DOM.

When you append your child nodes after parsing your XML file as XML, what you end up inserting are XML elements, not HTML elements. Since an HTML processor only understands HTML `link` elements, it does not recognize them when they come from an XML DOM — they become unknown elements, and do not have their intended meaning.

When you append the response markup directly, that markup is interpreted as HTML because you are working directly with the HTML DOM in your page. This allows your `link` elements to work as intended, referencing external stylesheets for use with your page.

---

The following example, with a non-head element, demonstrates how a `b` element differs between HTML and XML using the same methods in your question. In HTML, it represents [text that is meant to stand out from a paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element), with associated default styles. In plain XML, it's just an arbitrary element, with no default styles. In Firefox and IE, each `b` element also responds to namespaced CSS selectors correctly (note that they use the XHTML namespace even with HTML elements), although IE doesn't insert the XML element at all, instead throwing a `WrongDocumentError`. The included CSS doesn't work very well in Chrome either — presumably because, as with IE, trying to wrangle HTML and XML together isn't exactly the smartest thing to do.

```js
$(function() {
  var html = '<b>HTML b element</b>';
  var xml = '<root><b>XML b element</b></root>';

  $('p.html').append(html);

  var xmlDoc = jQuery.parseXML(xml);
  $('p.xml').append(xmlDoc.querySelector(':root').childNodes);
});
```

```css
@namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';

b::before {
  content: 'Default namespace ';
}

|b::before {
  content: 'Non-namespaced ';
}

/* Any or no namespace */
*|b {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="html"></p>
<p class="xml"></p>
```

What's interesting is that if you use `xml.querySelector("head").innerHTML` rather than `xml.querySelector("head").childNodes`, it seems to work, despite the fact that the `Element` object is not an `HTMLElement` (i.e. `xml.querySelector("head") instanceof HTMLElement` returns false). According to [this new answer by Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170911/does-innerhtml-work-with-xml-elements/25789924#25789924), in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome `innerHTML` represents the XML serialization of the contents of an XML element node, which explains this behavior. However, this particular quirk of `innerHTML` should not be relied on as it is not cross-browser compatible.

Ultimately, your best option is to not parse your document as XML in the first place; simply treat it as a regular HTML fragment by appending `responseText` directly, as jQuery is able to handle HTML fragments.

Comment: Thank you for such a well researched and explanative answer!