# Is there an alternative to XML.innerHTML in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a web app that takes XML and styles it with CSS. To display the XML as HTML, I have some JavaScript like:

```
document.getElementById("reportBody").innerHTML = myXml.innerHTML;
```

This works great in Chrome and Firefox, but Microsoft Edge treats `.innerHTML` as undefined for XML. Is there a different function I should be using that works better across browsers? Why does Edge treat `innerHTML` differently than the others?

After reading [This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170911/does-innerhtml-work-with-xml-elements) I tried using an XMLSerializer to get the XML to display in the html:

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var myXmlString = s.serializeToString(myXml);
document.getElementById("reportBody").innerHTML = myXmlString;
```

I don't like this way though, as `serializeToString` serializes the entire xml (including the parent element), instead of the children of the parent node. Is there a better way to do this that works across more browsers?

Comment: You can climb the XML with DOM methods to whichever node you're interested in before serializing. Once you found the element you like, you can create a temporary DIV and write to it with innerHTML, then grab its innerHTML before writing to reportBody. Do note innerHTML won't play well with html containing JavaScript, but there's frameworks out there like jQuery which you can use that offers the `.html(...)` method etc

Comment: Heh, for once I agree with Microsoft's choices. Also, have you considered using XSLT to style your XML? It's literally what it's made for. Of course I don't expect you to change language if you've got a nearly-working solution, but the next times you might want to consider it.

Comment: I have tried a quick test at https://jsfiddle.net/foowr6rx/ and for me with Edge (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393) on an up to date Windows 10 `innerHTML` is not undefined and the assigment and the CSS styling works. So consider to edit your question and show us a minimal but complete code snippet that does not work with Edge.

Comment: @MartinHonnen your jsfiddle is exactly what I'm trying to do. It didn't work in my version of Edge, so I checked the version and sure enough, my version is old. I thought Edge updated automatically, turns out it doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your version of Microsoft Edge is at least 14. `XML.innerHTML` does work in Microsoft Edge now.